# Unable to Save Any New File Created Through GUIs

Tags: permissions, libreoffice, gui

I have installed the Latest LTS Ubuntu Release - 20.04.
I get a peculiar problem. When I use gedit and open a file it becomes possible to save it. However, when I open a new text file through Libre Office, or a new .cpp file through Codeblocks, the Save As just doesn't work. When I click on the save as option, the screen turns darker but doesn't change, and I don't see the save as popup anywhere. I have tried various fixes but none of them work. Can you please help me?

Edit - I think  I now found the exact problem. Save As Simply doesn't work anywhere. Why is this happening and what is the fix for this?

Edit 2 - Another clarification considering that I received one answer. There doesn't seem to be a problem when I am creating folders whenever I want. I can also create files through the terminal, write something into them and save it. The problem arises when I create a new file through the GUI and ask it to save. The screen turns darker and I can't do anything. Also, the same happens when I try to upload files on a browser and I click the upload button - the screen turns darker and I can't do any operation. Pressing esc reverts the screen back to normalcy. So what should I do?

Edit 3 - Here are the logs for when I try to open a new window:

Apr  5 16:51:59 dell-B85M-DS3H-A gnome-shell[1820]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.

This is what I think is the error. It repeated itself 7 mins later when I tried a file upload through firefox. What is going wrong?

Comment: It's the latest LTS. Please excuse me if some of the facts are incorrect - I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: *The screen turns darker and I can't do anything* implies that there is a dialog (popup) box open requesting your input, which is expected behavior. If you use multiple Workspaces, check all of them. Also note the exact time this occurs, and check your /var/log/syslog for relevant system messages that occurred at the time. If so, copy them into your Question.